# How to add existing Library to my iPhone project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

So, Not a very sophisticated question, but since I never did it before I need your advice.

I have my main project, which includes 2 more sub projects that produces static libraries that the main project uses.
Now, I want to add a Loggin framework to my project, and I want to be able to use it inside my main project and inside my static libraries as well.
As you can witness [here](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger/wiki/Integrating-NSLogger-in-your-application), it's not very hard, only 3 files needs to be included.

However, I'm not sure what's the best way to do it.
Adding those 3 files to each of the projects would probably cause symbols redefinition.
Adding to just one of the static libraries is not enough, unless I make the other one dependent on it, which is not quite correct logically.
I can probably make another static library project from these 3 files, and make my project and my 2 other sub projects dependent on it, but it feels like an overkill.

What's the best course of action here ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting those files in yet another separate library or framework would be my take.

You should perhaps reconsider if you really need your sub projects precompiled in static libraries (what advantage is that providing to you? are they really that huge that recompiling them now and then is that bothersome?).

A single Xcode project with everything on it might be a better solution, and is what I usuallly favor these days. That way you also don't have to worry about missing architectures in your libs or having compiled the lib with a compiler version and the main project with another, bugs within the libs can be debugged and traced more easily, etc…

Comment: The reason was never saving compilation time, putting those sub project just as source files inside 1 main project wouldn't incur any overhead in compilation, cause unless the files are changed they won't get compiled again, and if they do change they (or the static lib) would have to be recompiled anyway. Correct me If I'm wrong here and I miss something. The main reason for the separation was that those 2 static libraries are used both in my iPhone and my Mac application.

Comment: Moreover, it's a separate logic that can be applied to any future project I may have as well. Anyway, It's a shame I would have to create another static library sub project just for these 3 files tho. hope another suggestion will pop.

Comment: @Julio - because sometimes you might want one project to use different compiler settings to another.  e.g. c++11